# MS SQL Delete rows where gap between dates is over 360 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Good day

How I can delete rows which have a gap of 360 days between them E.G. in row 2 and 3

```
Table1 
Column1 Column2    Column3 
Fish      Blue      2016-12-14 23:51:25.653    
Dog       Brown     2017-09-14 23:51:25.653 ---  need to be deleted   
Dog       Black     2015-11-14 23:51:25.653 ---  need to be deleted     
Mouse     Red       2017-04-14 23:51:25.653      
Cat       Ping      2017-03-14 23:51:25.653     
Cat       Ping      2017-07-14 23:51:25.653
Mouse     Red       2016-10-14 23:51:25.653
```

Thanks for Opinion

Comment: " gap between self over 360 days" means? What is the criteria?

Comment: The data difference alone is the delete condition? 2017-09-14 isn't 360 days from 2017-07-14...

Comment: jarlh@ but 2017-09-14 - 2015-11-14  is over 360?

Comment: @Tester Is your "Column2" has any significance for which rows needs to be deleted?

Comment: Amit@  2017-09-14 - 2015-11-14 is over 360 is over 360 and need to be delete..

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Look at LAG, so you can compare rows to one another.

Comment: Chintak Chhapia@ column 2 No only column3 base on PK from Column1

Comment: i think over 360 means the difference of current date and column three date is more than 360 days...

Comment: how are you even deciding which dates should be checked for gap?

Comment: But difference between 2015-11-14 23:51:25.653 and 2017-04-14 23:51:25.653 is also bigger than 360. Why shouldn't we delete them too?

Comment: @Thebeginner The second row is from current year so the gap is not from current date.

Comment: The beginner@ is not current date.

Comment: @yeou base on PK from Column1

Comment: @Tester are you sure column1 is Pk? Its not unique.

Comment: @Yeou it is PK , but dates di different..

Comment: @Tester is it a combination of column1+column3? you need to read more about Primary key it should be unique for every row, and you have redundant data. please edit you question and put some more information.

Comment: @yeou its PK from oter tables..
 I start set up LAG function recommendet by Leonidas199x
mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3468/sql-servers-lag-and-lead-functions-to-help-identify-date-differences

Comment: Essentially, you want to delete everything from the table, except 1 record per year. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM [TableName] WHERE DATEDIFF(day,column3, GETDATE()) > 360
```

Comment: Read the comments before answering

Comment: @Thebeginner No, the comments shouldn't be necessary to understand the question. The point is that if the question is correctly formulated, then we don't have to guess what the OP wants, and we don't have to trawl through comments to glean an understanding of what the OP wants.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Just realised that I did misunderstand the question.